# Find all rows that contains 4 specific values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using excel and I have a table of numbers with 6 columns from A to F and more than 1000 rows. For example, from my table,

4   17  37  38  47  53
8   43  54  55  56  60
4   18  21  25  38  57
15  25  37  38  58  59
4   16  19  20  27  43
18  32  47  50  54  56

i want to find if there is at least a row (**it must be a row!**) that contains the numbers 16 19 20 27. From this example, there is a match, but i don't know how to make a search or formula using **four** diferent numbers.

I feel like I need to use the match function but can't quite figure it out and I'm not sure about it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Build a helper column that concatenates all 6 columns then do an if statement? Edit: hmm this only works if all 4 are consecutive XD

Comment: that's the problem. it can be consecutive or not!
using my table example, it could be a search like this:
4 25 38 57
so, the line 3 is a match.
is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=IF(AND(OR(A1=16,B1=16,C1=16,D1=16,E1=16,F1=16),OR(A1=19,B1=19,C1=19,D1=19,E1=19,F1=19),OR(A1=20,B1=20,C1=20,D1=20,E1=20,F1=20),OR(A1=27,B1=27,C1=27,D1=27,E1=27,F1=27)),"Yes","No")
```

Put it in a new column in the table. It will return a `Yes` if the row contains all 4 values, and a `No` otherwise. You can then filter the new column of Yes/No to search for a row with `Yes`

Answer (score 0):

I put the four values you are seeking in `I1:L1` and the array of data to be searched in `A1:F#`. Then in column `G` create a helper column that concatenates `A:F` into a delimited string. The formula in `G1` is:

```
=":"&A1&":"&B1&":"&C1&":"&D1&":"&E1&":"&F1&":"
```

where I've used ":" for the delimiter (you can use any char that's not in your data).

The result in `G1` is:

```
:4:17:37:38:47:53:
```

Now in `H1` use this formula to search:

```
=NOT(ISERR(FIND(":"&$I$1&":",G1)*FIND(":"&$J$1&":",G1)*FIND(":"&$K$1&":",G1)*FIND(":"&$L$1&":",G1)))
```

Each `FIND` will return an INT if the value (with leading and trailing delimiters) is found and #VALUE! otherwise. So the product will be an INT if all values are found and #VALUE! otherwise. Wrapping the `FINDs` inside an `ISERR` makes the result prettier (TRUE/FALSE instead of #VALUE!), and inverting with `NOT` returns TRUE when all 4 values are found and FALSE otherwise.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way --- more elegant (no helper column). As before, I put the four values you are seeking in `I1:L1` and the array of data to be searched in `A1:F#`. Then in column `G` use this ARRAY formula (CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER):

```
=NOT(OR(PRODUCT(A1:F1-$I$1)<>0,PRODUCT(A1:F1-$J$1)<>0,PRODUCT(A1:F1-$K$1)<>0,PRODUCT(A1:F1-$L$1)<>0))
```

Each `PRODUCT` term checks for the existence of one value and returns `0` when the value is found and a non-zero value otherwise. The results of each of the four `PRODUCT` terms is tested with `<>0` which will return TRUE if a value is not found. Then OR with return TRUE if one or more values are *not* found and FALSE if *all* are found. That result is wrapped in a NOT so that the function result is TRUE when all four values are found.